# Open new activity from actionbox menu item and close actually activity

Tags: java, android-activity, menu

How can i open an activity only one time? If i click more times on the same item in menu it open more times. Is there a way to close the actually viewed activity when open a new one?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //menu item clickd
    if (id == R.id.share) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HowToUse.class));
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.terms) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InfoAbout.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.howuse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HowToUse.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the soulion add.Flags to clear the top

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //menu item clickd
    if (id == R.id.share) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HowToUse.class));
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.terms) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InfoAbout.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (id == R.id.howuse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HowToUse.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```